# PHP mysql connections help ( ubuntu LAMP server)

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-ec2, lamp

So last night I had a cpu spike for 100% for 30 minutes which made the server not very usable :-(

The server doesn't seem to be the quickest even today (its running on Amazon cloud!).

The application is a chat application which only has about registered 5 users who's client polls a php script every every 5 seconds for new information ( each request hits mysql).

Running some commands I found on the net it returned that I have 200 thousand connections - is this active or since the server was up?

Can anyon offer any advice if there is anything out of the ordinary in the below.

(Note these stats are from today where there were only 2 users logged in)

[image]

Comment: Did you check to see which processes were using the CPU? Are you sure it's MySQL? Nothing looks strange in the output you posted. With Max_used_connections only at 144, unless you were doing some crazy queries, I doubt this would max your CPU. What database engine are you using?

Comment: removed the simpledb tag as its not relevant

Answer (score 0):

120 thosand connections since your mysql running up. About 100% of cpu. Check apache logs in /var/logs/apacheX looking for excessive error messages. It can be the server slow.